# Eigen assertion error at compile time, unclear error

Tags: c++, eigen

So I'm trying to make a class that basically acts as an interface with an Eigen Matrix for partitioning, along with a few additional features. A basic replica of my data structure is:

```
template <class T>
class DataFile {
public:
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<DataType, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> RMatrix;
    DataFile(int inputRows, int inputColumns) {
        dataMatrix = RMatrix::Zero(inputRows, inputColumns);
    }
    inline typename RMatrix::RowXpr getSample(const int row) { return dataMatrix.row(row) }

private:
    RMatrix dataMatrix;
```

This is just a simplistic look at what I did and what seems to be relevant. When I compile my code using Qtcreator and MSVC2008, I get the following error message:

```
c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h(390) : error C2039: 'THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD' : is not a member of 'Eigen::internal::static_assertion<condition>'
        with
        [
            condition=false
        ]
        c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h(388) : while compiling class template member function 'float &Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived,Level>::operator [](__int64)'
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1>,
            Level=1
        ]
        c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h(653) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived,Level>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1>,
            Level=1
        ]
        c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/util/XprHelper.h(365) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1>
        ]
        c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/DenseBase.h(53) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::internal::special_scalar_op_base<Derived,Scalar,OtherScalar>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1>,
            Scalar=float,
            OtherScalar=float
        ]
        c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/MatrixBase.h(65) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1>
        ]
        c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h(89) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1>
        ]
        c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/Matrix.h(144) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,1>
        ]
        d:\users\public\documents\myCode\DataFilesV2.h(46) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols,_Options>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Scalar=float,
            _Rows=-1,
            _Cols=-1,
            _Options=1
        ]
c:\apis_x64\eigen-eigen-ca142d0540d3\eigen\src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h(390) : error C2065: 'THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD' : undeclared identifier
```

The line `d:\users\public\documents\myCode\DataFilesV2.h(46)` reffers to the line `inline typename RMatrix::RowXpr getSample(const int row) { return dataMatrix.row(row) }` in my code. I've been able to get this work in other parts of my code before, so my thought was it was something that was calling it. However, in all the times that I call this, there's no usage of []'s or improper use of the `RowXpr.` I have a lot of code to go through, so I'm not really sure how to find this error and could use some ideas on either what may be going wrong or how I can hunt down what's causing the error.

Comment: Did you see the `'THE_BRACKET_OPERATOR_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS__USE_THE_PARENTHESIS_OPERATOR_INSTEAD'` part of the error message? Also I would look at line 365 of `XprHelper.h`.

Comment: Yes, I did see that part. That's why I searched through my code looking for usage of [] operators applied to any vectors constructed by my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding the error, which was what Eigen had said it was. I had a leftover [] from conversion from an array to an Eigen matrix. But the problem wasn't even remotely related to where the error was pointing at. I had to go through and comment out where the error was pointing at until finally the error went away, and I could deduce which part of the code was the true source of the error.

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem, error was indicated at the wrong location. In my case, i had changed the type of a variable from VectorXd to MatrixXd, but had used later in this code the x() member, which propably uses internally the []-Operator.

Answer (score 1):

Once I fixed the missing semicolon in the definition of `getSample`, both g++-4.8 and clang++-3.3 compile the simple test case below (basically your example with a trivial `DataType` struct):

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>

struct DataType
{
    double x;
};

template <class T>
class DataFile {
public:
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<DataType, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> RMatrix;
    DataFile(int inputRows, int inputColumns) {
        dataMatrix = RMatrix::Zero(inputRows, inputColumns);
    }
    inline typename RMatrix::RowXpr getSample(const int row) { return dataMatrix.row(row); }

private:
    RMatrix dataMatrix;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation was fine:

```
$ clang++-mp-3.3 -I/opt/local/include/eigen3 test.cpp
$ g++ -I/opt/local/include/eigen3 test.cpp
```

So, apart from the semicolon, your example appears fine to me.  Does my example compile for you?

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to get your code to work. I've done this in another class as well, and I get no errors there.